# Ant give Error creating temporary file

Tags: java, ant, build

I'm currently fighting for a few hour now with ant because of this error

```
[javac] Compiling 124 source files to /home/prod/svn.build/path1/my_plugin/build

BUILD FAILED
/home/prod/svn.build/path1/my_plugin/build.xml:74: Error creating temporary file
```

the line in question is :

```
<javac fork="true" source="${javac.source}" target="${javac.target}" debug="${javac.debug}"     
            srcdir="${source.dir}"
            destdir="${build.dir}"
            classpathref="libraries" memoryinitialsize="256m" memorymaximumsize="256m">
    </javac>
```

However this been working for year and is working perfectly on my local environement but when I run this on our dev server it doesn't work. 
Note that I have admin access to to all these directory so it's shouldn't be a access problem.

What can cause the build file to file remotely and not locally ? 
Can it be something really stupid like there no more space to build the class ?

Comment: What is your $TMPDIR, do you have enough space, is it writeable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually the server we were using, we rebooted the box and now everything is fine.